# How can we make it so that when the user clicks on 'sign,' it automatically affects their saved signature?

Tags: docusignapi

I am working on Laravel 8 with PHP 8.1 and using the DocuSign API.

At the moment, **DocuSign** keeps asking me to fetch a saved **signature** every time.

Example :

1. **[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAlE8.png)**
2. **[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9CuX.png)**
3. **[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGVvy.png)**

I would like that when the user clicks on "anchor_string" **DocuSign** **automatically** **applies** **the** **user's** **signature** without asking them to retrieve it every time.

Example :

1. **[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAlE8.png)**
2. No step 2 in the signing process.
3. **[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGVvy.png)**

How can we make it so that when the user clicks on 'sign,' it automatically affects their saved signature ?

Comment: When you say "every time" do you mean within the same envelope/document? or do you mean you run your code again, and then? 
Second question, do you always send to the same email/name combination?

Comment: Are you using embedded signing or remote signing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @InbarGazit, first of all, thank you for helping me with this issue. 
So, for the first question, I don't quite understand when you say 'you run your code again, and then?' And for the second one, I always use the same combination of name/email. The process is: I create a purchase order, if the total is less than 100, it's Mr. A, then the buyer who signs. Otherwise, if equal to or greater than 100, it's Mr. A, then Mr. B, and finally, the buyer signs. So, Mr. A and B are always the same individuals, while the buyer can change depending on the purchase orders.

I use remote signing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for DocuSign to store/remember you signature (when it asks for you to "Adopt a signature" and does this extra steps), you have to have a DocuSign account.

The name and email of the signer must match **Exactly** to the one stored from before or else it would be considered a different singer.

You can get a free/trial account and that would allow you to that, but if the signer does not have any account at all (They cannot log-in to DocuSign securely) then DocuSign does not remember their signature.

Comment: So, the person who needs to sign, and is always the same, does indeed have an account with DocuSign. 
I'm wondering if the issue might be with my Signer object. Let me explain; is it possible that I haven't provided the correct information such as their 'name' or 'contact_id'?


`       $signer = new Signer([
                'email' => "john.doe@entreprise.fr",
                'name' => "Doe",
                'recipient_id' => 12345,
                'routing_order' => 1,
            ]);`

Comment: Does john.doe@entreprise.fr" have a DocuSign account?

Comment: Yes, he does have an account. In Settings, then in Users and Groups, and then in Users, I do find his name and first name listed in the Name column

Comment: Then that user, the exact name/email, if they adopt a signature and another one is sent to them - should be already adopted, and not ask to adopt a signature again. Assuming they log into DocuSign.

Comment: Hello, I just solved my problem. 
The issue was that I was swapping the first name and last name in the Signer class on the 'name' property. 

Now it works, there's no need to re-register my signature. DocuSign recognizes me directly and retrieves my signature. 

Thanks again for your help, without you, I wouldn't have realized it.

Comment: Yes, that would do it, let me update my answer a bit